# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'arvg' while accessing command line argument python

Tags: python, attributes, command-line-arguments, runtime-error, argv

My code to access command line argument:

```
length = len(sys.argv)
print length
str = sys.arvg[0]
print str
```

gives output :

```
triongle@triongle.com [~/download/DataInsertionScript]# python IngestDataToMongo.py python_sucks
2
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "IngestDataToMongo.py", line 83, in <module>
str = sys.arvg[0]
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'arvg'
```

So, first time len(sys.argv) works but strangely next time gives error on sys.argv[0]. So why is it?

Comment: Um, because you typed `arvg` instead of `argv`?

Comment: @BrenBarn for 1 hour, I was struggling because of a typing error :) thanks

Comment: I don't think you've invested enough time into this before asking. It's 4 lines, and you don't see the difference between argv and arvg?

Comment: how to delete this question? I'm not able to do that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have written `sys.arvg[0]` instead of `sys.argv[0]`. Also be sure to `import` the `sys` module, because argv by default belongs to that namespace.

Answer (score 2):

you have written `sys.arvg[0]` it should be `sys.argv[0]`

Answer (score 2):

You've misspelt `argv` as `arvg`.